# Good way to calculate Easter date (PERL)

Tags: perl

How I do to calculate correct holiday dates for a specific country, in this case sweden?
I know how to get saturdays and sundays, and exclude them from processing.

But theres other holidays, like christmas, national day, Christ skytraveller's day, thirteen's day, that are red Days and needs to be excluded in a attendance solution.

What I want to know, is how I do a function, given a specific year, month and day, will return true or false if it a holiday or not.

I looked on Date::Holidays but theres no data source for sweden, it says I need to create one myself. But the problem is more, how I do to calculate the correct dates? Is there a specific algoritm for getting holiday dates, for example easter?

Some holiday dates are easy to create out of a list, like christmas evening and new year that have fixed dates each year, but some holidays are different each year.

For example this is super complicated:

Easter: First sunday after the first ecklesaustic full moon after the spring equinox.

Most other dynamic holidays are calculated out of the Easter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how the dates of Swedish holidays are determined rather than programming per se.

Comment: @Quentin The question is related to programming, and is very useful in a programming context for other people that are creating applications that does something with dates, and needs to be aware of holidays.

Comment: Unless you need to have a calculation for any year in history, it's easier to make a static list of the holidays for, say, the next 10 years and make a note to update the list 10 years from now.  If you do need the data for an arbitrary year, then you'll just have to look up how each holiday is determined and implement the algorithm. This is a common task so all of them should be easily googleable.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen — A question in the form of "The holiday of *imadethisoneup* takes place on the third Sunday after the first Monday of June, how can I work out the date for this, in Perl, for any given year?" is a decent programming question. "What dates does Sweden have holidays on?" is not.

Comment: Updated the question with the most complicated one. The rest I can figure out of myself.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rbow/Date-Easter-1.22/lib/Date/Easter.pm, http://search.cpan.org/~rickm/DateTime-Event-Easter-1.04/lib/DateTime/Event/Easter.pm, https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+easter

Comment: The most likely resource to have a comprehensive list and to stay up to date would be a web API. Maybe http://holidayapi.com or https://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/holiday-api.html (although the latter is $100/year).

Comment: Questions asking for libraries are programming-related but still off-topic.  The question doesn't directly ask for this, but the title certainly seems to be begging for that sort of solution.

Comment: wasn't the updated title okay?

Comment: Latest release of [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/release/Time-Moment) supports calcutation of [Western Easter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment::Adjusters#WesternEasterSunday) and [Orthodox Easter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment::Adjusters#OrthodoxEasterSunday). Time::Moment aslo comes with an example of computing Swedish holidays, [eg/se_bank_holidays.pl](https://metacpan.org/source/CHANSEN/Time-Moment-0.41/eg/se_bank_holidays.pl).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my function I created out of it. It expects a year as a parameter, and will return a hash with all red Days (non-business Days) for sweden that year.

Note that it will NOT return any holidays that is Always a Saturday or Sunday, as Saturdays and Sundays is non-business anyways.

```
Requires Date::Calc and Date::Easter

    sub GetHoliDayList() {

    $yeartocheck = $_[0];

    $holiday{'1-1'} = '1';
    $holiday{'1-6'} = '1';
    $holiday{'5-1'} = '1';
    $holiday{'6-6'} = '1';
    $holiday{'6-24'} = '1';
    $holiday{'12-24'} = '1';
    $holiday{'12-25'} = '1';
    $holiday{'12-26'} = '1';
    $holiday{'12-31'} = '1';

    ($eastermonth, $easterday) = gregorian_easter( $yeartocheck );
    $hea = int($eastermonth)."-".int(int($easterday) - 2);
    $heb = int($eastermonth)."-".int(int($easterday) + 1);
    $holiday{$hea} = '1';
    $holiday{$heb} = '1';

    ($year,$christskytravellermonth,$christskytravellerday) = Add_Delta_YMD($yeartocheck,$eastermonth,$easterday, 0,0,39);
    $chstv = int($christskytravellermonth)."-".int($christskytravellerday);
    $holiday{$chstv} = '1';

    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,19) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-19'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,20) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-20'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,21) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-21'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,22) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-22'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,23) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-23'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,24) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-24'} = '1';
    }
    if (Day_of_Week($yeartocheck,6,25) == 5) {
    $holiday{'6-25'} = '1';
    }

    return %holiday;
    }
```